# How do I make an array of sub categories containing the prospective users?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables: `users`, `categories` and `categories_users`.

```
users table
- id
- name
- email
- etc...
```

```
categories table
- id
- name
- type
- etc...
```

```
categories_users table
- id
- categories_id
- users_id
- demo1
- demo2
- demo3
```

`demo2` is kind of like a sub category

What I need is to make an array with the (demo2 - sub categories) as keys and the prospective users as values under the appropriate (demo2 -sub category) so that I can loop through each category and get its users.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using laravel?

I have tried the following

```php
$category = Category::where('id', 12)->first();
$users = $category->users->sortBy('pivot.demo2');
$users_by_category = [];
$the_users = [];

foreach($users ?? [] as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == 0 OR $v->pivot->demo2 == $users[$k -1]->pivot->demo2 ) {
        $the_users[] = $v;
        $users_by_category[$v->pivot->demo2] = $the_users;
    } elseif ($v->pivot->demo2 != $users[$k -1]->pivot->demo2 ) {
        $users_by_category[$v->pivot->demo2] = $the_users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that without a loop thanks to Collections.

```php
$category = Category::with('users')->find(12);
$users_by_category = $category->users->groupBy('pivot.demo2')->all();
```